# How to make 'Views' consider contextual filter value to be 'all' automatically?

Tags: views

What I am trying achieve here(d7) is a bit cleaner URLs which is looking odd due to **8-12 contextual filters.** Except 1 or 2 filters others will be `/all` most of the times.

Suppose I have 5 contextual filters. When only the first one has value, the URL becomes `example.com/24/all/all/all/all`. Is there a way we can avoid "`/all/all/all/all`" ?

I have also tried using query parameters through PHP CODE.

If I choose *'Provide default value' ->  'PHP code' and use*

```
$query= $_GET['clr'];
return $query;
```

Is there a way we can tell views to consider "`query=all`" for other queries automatically if that part is omitted in URL?

For ex: 
If URL is

> example.com?clr=1234

the view should assume it to be

> example.com?q1=all&q2=all&q3=all&q4=all&clr=1234

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it clashes with your configuration, but usually you use the option **Display all results for the specified field** under `When the filter value is NOT available`.

---

There is also the option under `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided` > `Specify validation criteria`:

**Action to take if filter value does not validate**

where you can choose to `Display all results for the specified field`. Maybe you can combine it with some Validation conditions to achieve what you want.

Comment: Even if it is "Display all results for the specified field", the parameter is needed in URL. Otherwise it goes to "Page Not Found".

Comment: Not necessarily, I guess it depends on your other options.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find solution for contextual filter. But the behavior I wanted is achieve is possible by using

`Filter Criteria (Exposed)` instead of `Contextual filter`.

Here instead of using `Exposed Filter form`,  I am providing `Links` which is working fine.